# Assigning array of struct fails

Tags: arrays, struct, malloc

This simple code crashes (Segmentation fault) and I don't understand why. Seems like this [] operation does not work properly with an array of structures. Maybe somebody knows the reason behind this weird behavior.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <string.h>

#define SIZE 3

typedef struct{
  int a;
  char * b;
}qwe;

void foo ( qwe **out){
  int i;

  *out = (qwe*)malloc(SIZE*sizeof(qwe));

  for (i=0;i<SIZE;i++){
    out[i]->a = i;
    out[i]->b = strdup("Hello");
  }
}

int main() {
  int i = 0;
  qwe *p = NULL;

  foo(&p);

  for (i=0;i<SIZE;i++)      
    printf("Int: %d, str: %s \n",p[i].a , p[i].b);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the declaration `qwe *p = NULL;` you are not declaring an array of pointers but of the actual `struct`.
But in `foo` you are dereferrencing the arrays content as pointer and that is not correct.
Your approach can be rewritten like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i<SIZE; i++) {
    (*out)[i].a = i;
    (*out)[i].b = _strdup("Hello");
}
```

Another approach that makes the dereferrency better readable (in my opinion) would be to pass a reference to the array:

```
void foo1(qwe *& out) {
    out = (qwe*)malloc(SIZE * sizeof(qwe));
    for (int i = 0; i<SIZE; i++) {
        out[i].a = i;
        out[i].b = _strdup("Hello");
    }
}
```